# How can I change my buttons outline style when focused back to the browsers default value after using all: unset;

Tags: css

I am tired of different browsers using different default stylings for buttons and unexpectedly changing it which causes my buttons to look weird all the time. Therefore, I want to unset all stylings that browsers add to my buttons so that I can style them myself in peace!

However, what I don't want, it I don't want to unset the browsers default outline value as this would be an accessibility issue and I do not want to create my own outline style.

I tried using `outline: initial;` to reset the value to the default value for that element, however, as you can see in the snippet if you tab through the elements, it is not working.

```css
button {
    all: unset;
    cursor: pointer;
}
button:focus {
    outline: initial;
}
```

```html
<div><a href="#">MY LINK</a></div>
<br>
<div><button>MY BUTTON</button></div>
<br>
<div><a href="#">MY LINK</a></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is below, (attempted) explanatory comments are in the text but I think it's broadly self-evident how it works:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  gap: 1rem;
}

body > * {
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
  flex-basis: 20%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  all: unset;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* this adds the browser's default value back to
   all elements that match the below selectors,
   this could easily be restricted to only
   <button> elements of course: */
:focus, :active, :focus-visible {
  outline: auto;
}
```

```html
<!-- I decluttered the HTML, removing <div> and
     and <br> elements: -->
<a href="#">MY LINK</a>
<button>MY BUTTON</button>
<a href="#">MY LINK</a>
<!-- added the <label> and <input> to add another
     focus-able/tab-able element -->
<label>Sample input: <input></label>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/q5m9t4wu/).

As to *why* it works, the [spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui/#outline) for the `outline` property states that the `initial` value of the `outline` is determined by the `initial` state of the individual properties. This leads us to look at the `outline-style`, in which the `initial` state is defined as `none`, so there is no visible `outline`.

Back in the notes for the `outline` spec, we can see that:

> ...[in] the ambiguous case where a lone auto value is specified, or if auto is specified together with an <'outline-width'> value, but without an explicit <'outline-style'> or <'outline-color'> value, both outline-style and outline-color are set to auto.

The [spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui/#propdef-outline-style) for the `outline-style` property says the following:

> The auto value permits the user agent to render a custom outline style, typically a style which is either a user interface default for the platform, or perhaps a style that is richer than can be described in detail in CSS

So, setting all styles to `initial` effectively removes the outline-style which renders the outline as non-visible, whereas the `auto` value restores the browser's default style.

References:

- [`outline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline), [specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui/#outline).
- [`outline-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline-color), [specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui/#propdef-outline-color).
- [`outline-style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline-style), [specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui/#propdef-outline-style).
- [`outline-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline-width), [specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui/#propdef-outline-width).

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer, this helps a lot. I did however notice that the outline color is not correct on chrome and edge. Chrome and edge uses blue for all outlines, but using ```outline: auto;``` gives black on buttons and inputs. I assume this is just a chromium issue tho?